# How are runtime configurations set in grafana loki?

Tags: grafana-loki

With grafana loki, I see that to be able to delete logs, a runtime configuration should be set as explained [here](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/operations/storage/logs-deletion/)

I could not find the relevant documentation on how to set runtime configuration for loki ?

Any help is appreciated.